# How to make a monthly boxplot for each group in a data frame in python

Tags: python, pandas, boxplot

I have some data like this:

```
    Export Country  Import Terminal  Arrival Date  Value
     Country            Port A         1/15     135138
     Country            Port A         1/15     153232
     Country            Port A         3/15     116116
        .                  .             .           .
        .                  .             .           .
        .                  .             .           .
        .                  .             .           .
     Country            Port B         1/15     155462
     Country            Port B         2/15     116532
     Country            Port B         1/16     456321
     Country            Port B         2/16     865313
        .                  .             .           .
        .                  .             .           .
        .                  .             .           .
        .                  .             .           .
```

I used df = df.groupby(['Import Terminal', 'Arrival Date'])[Value].sum() and ended with:

```
Import Terminal   Arrival    Sum of Value 
    Port A         1/15        288370
                   3/15        116116
                     .            .
                     .            .
    Port B         1/15        155462
                     .            .
                     .            .
```

Now I need to go through each Import Terminal and make a monthly box plot for each one, using the Arrival Month and Sum of Value columns. How can I do this, I am lost on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example with dummy data:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Export Country': np.random.randint(0,10,1000),
    'Import Terminal': np.random.randint(0,3,1000),
    'Arrival Date': np.random.randint(0,10,1000),
    'Value':np.random.randint(0,10,1000),})

gb = df.groupby(['Import Terminal', 'Arrival Date'])['Value'].sum().reset_index()
gb['month'] = gb['Arrival Date'].apply(lambda x: int(x.split('/')[0]))
for terminal, group in gb.groupby('Import Terminal'):
    group.boxplot(by='month', column='Value')
    plt.suptitle('Import terminal {}'.format(terminal))
    plt.title('')
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's closer than I have gotten so far but I'm trying to get a box plot for each Import Terminal, with a box showing the values for each month.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas provides a boxplot function of the DataFrame, see documentation here:  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.boxplot.html .

You can create a box plot in your case like this :

```
df.reset_index().boxplot(by=['Arrival Date']
```

Another (more verbose and explicit) way would be to construct the boxplot in matplotlib directly.

Why reset_index ?
The result you have presented is (probably) a Series (single column data frame) with a MultiIndex index and as such does not have a boxplot method (strangely, right?). You could make it a DataFrame by reset_index or by casting to a DataFrame `df2 = pd.DataFrame(df)` , or using `as_index=False` argument of a groupby

The plot for your partial data looks like this
[image]

Each box-group will summarise the 'Sum of Value' response variable values of all observations for each Arrival Data (i.e. from both A and B, or all Import Terminals). Presumably you want each terminal data taken separately, as you need to "go through each terminal".
If you need to slice the data and create a separate box plot for each Terminal (with values grouped in boxes by month) then my suggestion is to get the list of terminals by `terminals=df2['Import Terminal'].unique()` and iterate through the terminal list subsetting the data frame (hint
`df_subs = df[ df['Import Terminal'] == value]` ) and for each subset creating the boxplot like above.

Note that pandas uses matplotlib under the hood for the boxplot and matplotlib must be installed in your environment.

If you could provide error messages and the python packages you have available / want to use then perhaps I could help further. For example you could use other packages which wrap the plots even nicer than pandas (e.g. seaborn, see catplots https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/categorical.html )

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.catplot(x="Arrival Date", y="Value", hue="Import Terminal", kind="box", data=df2)
```

It is not clear what is the format of the Arrival date and if you need to calculate months from them, if this is 'month/year' then all you need is sort them appropriately for the X axis.